# Making css image absolute paths goto the root of a sub directory, not the root of the main domain

Tags: css, .htaccess, subdirectory

I have multiple sites for clients set up on a single development domain.  So the structure looks like this:

developmentdomain.com/client1/site

developmentdomain.com/client2/site
developmentdomain.com/client/anothersite

Every things works fine (including furls) if i have a base ref in the html and add a RewriteBase rule my htaccess file.

But for some if within the css i have:

```
background: url("/assets/images/someImage.png");
```

Its trying to find the image at this location:
developmentdomain.com/assets/images/someImage.png

When it needs to be looking at:
developmentdomain.com/client1/site/assets/images/someImage.png

I'm guessing i need to do a rewrite rule in the htacess, but what?

Oh and this is what i have in the htacces file for my RewriteBase

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /client1/site
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks
Ben

Comment: I like my dev sites to be identical to the production site so I use subdomains rather than folders to segregate projects.

Answer (score 0):

No need for rewrite rules. You just need to use relative urls instead of root-relative. So use:

```
background: url("assets/images/someImage.png");
```

or `background: url("/images/someImage.png");` if the css is located in the assets folder. (You could use `../` to go up one folder if needed)

Comment: Hi Gerben, thanks for the reply.  I wanted to avoid using the relative urls as it site thats already created and i'm trying to get it working without having to go through and manually change all the background image references.  Whats more annoying is all the current references are different.  Some use root and other don't and there's even multiple image folders so no quick find and replace option.

Comment: Find `url("/path/to/css` and replace `url("`. Won't work if the images are not located in (a subfolder of) the css's folder. There is no way to do this with rewriterules as you don't know if `/assets/images/someImage.png` was requested from client1 or from clients2, so you don't know if it should become `/client1/site/assets/images/someImage.png` or `/client2/site/assets/images/someImage.png`. You could do this by checking the referer, but that won't always work.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  But that's the problem as the current site i'm working on, the original creator of the css has linked to images all over the place and some are outside of the css folder.  But each site will have it's own htaccess file so i can manually add the correct path for each sites htaccess file. Thanks