# Shown image in css instead <div> img src</div>

Tags: css

I would like to replace

```
<div><img src="/mod/EmpTheme/free1/img/2843_3_base.png" /></div>
```

with

```
<div class="tempbtm"></div>
```

and put

```
.tempbtm { background:url(/mod/EmpTheme/free1/img/2843_3_base.png) left top no-repeat; }
```

inside css file. The problem is if I do that no image shown.

http://jsfiddle.net/nNw62/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must specify a width and height for the container.

Answer (score 0):

what is the image size? It may be showing the white content of the image in that `div` making you think that its not working. Your code is correct and when i changed the image its working.
or it may be [directory linking problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8359584/1577396)